# Similar matrix for numerical computations

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I compute numerically a symmetric matrix $W$ from the flow of a ode. I have to check numerically if this matrix is definite-positive.
Two cases:

- either I use the Cholesky algorithm :ok
- or I compute the eigenvalues. It appears that in theory, $W$ has zero eigenvalues, let say $\lambda$ and numerically I can check that when I increase the precision (absolute and relative) of the ode integrator, $\lambda$ becomes smaller while the other eigenvalues, let say $\gamma$, don't change.
  However, the ratio of $\frac{\lambda }{ \min(\gamma)}$ is not small ($10^{-7}$) with respect
  to the machine precision ($10^{-22}$).

**Question**: *How can I find a similar matrix $S$ to $W$ so that $S$ is well conditionned
to compute the eigenvalues (in the sense that $\lambda / \gamma$ will be closer to the machine precision) ?*

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? In the traditional definition of matrix similarity, the eigenvalues are unchanged.

Comment: yep that's this definition (or any transformation/conditioning that preserves the spectrum of $W$)

Comment: Sorry, then what is your goal? If $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ are preserved then what is changing?

Comment: I would like to inscrease the precision of the computations of $\lambda$ because analytically, $\lambda$ is zero and $\gamma > 0$ so when I increase the precision, $\gamma$ is unchanged and $\lambda$ becomes smaller. However, due to time of computations and limits of integrator, I can't get $\lambda$ very small (of order $10^{-4}$). I would like to know if by making the computations on a similar matrix (typically I tried to divide W by its Frobenius norm) I could get $\lambda$ of smaller order.